# Want to create a tab delimited file with autonumbers

Tags: python, numbers

I would like to create a tab delimited file with Python and add autonumbering 001 - 002 - 003 - ... to 10 in first column and 011 - 012 - 013 in second "column"
I try to create 2 variables and don't know how to add the leading zero's part. Also writing the variables gives a error message.

```
lst1 = list(range(1,10+1))
lst2 = list(range(11,20+1))

#zero_filled_number = number_str.zfill(3)

with open('numbers2.txt', 'w') as f:
   # f.write('Start')
   f.write((lst1) + "\t" + (lst2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `zip` to easily pair the dofferent list, when apply `zfill` on each value and `str.join` to add the tab between each

```
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    for row in zip(lst1, lst2):
        row_str = "\t".join(str(x).zfill(3) for x in row)
        f.write(row_str + "\n")


001 011
002 012
003 013
004 014
...
```

Comment: Thank you Azro that's indeed what i wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

`"{0:03}".format(i)` will output a string with 0s on the left.

For example if `i` is **12**, it will return the string `"012"`.

Answer (score 0):

The function `zfill` that you suggested can be used on strings. To convert a number to string, use str(number). With some list comprehension, I hope the example below will be helpful:

```py
lst1 = list(range(1,10+1))

lst1_str = [str(x).zfill(3) for x in lst1]
print(lst1_str)
```

Output

```
['001', '002', '003', '004', '005', '006', '007', '008', '009', '010']
```